# Char vs unsigned char in conversion to int

Tags: c, char, data-conversion, unsigned

I stumbled upon this problem while saving an int in a char array and converting it back. I used bit shifts and logic or, but my result ended up with all the bytes after the least significant as 0xFF.

My question is: considering this example

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
        char c1 = 0x86;
        unsigned char c2 = 0x86;
        unsigned int i1 = 0, i2 = 0;

        i1 = (unsigned int) c1;
        i2 = (unsigned int) c2;

        printf("%x-%x\n", i1, i2);
}
```

Why is the output `ffffff86-86`? Why does the char have all its upper bits set to 1?

I'm sure there is a very simple answer, but I couldn't come up with a specific enough query to find it on google.

Comment: I didn't know about two's complement, and I though negative values where handled with a single bit. As I said, I had no idea how to put this concept into words and query it on google. You can either provide an answer or, if you have the power to, flag this question as invalid. Passive-aggressive comments achieve nothing but wasting your time.

Comment: Yes there is a simple answer: enable compiler warnings. And then never use the `char` type for any other purpose than storing characters - see linked duplicates. Use `uint8_t` for raw binary data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's implementation defined if a `char` is signed or unsigned.

If `char` is signed, then when being [promoted to an `int`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/conversion#Integer_promotions) it will be *sign extended*, so a negative value will keep its negative value after the promotion.

The leading `1` bits is how negative numbers are represented in [two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two's_complement) systems, which is the most common way to handle negative numbers.

---

If, with your compiler, `char` is signed (which it seems to be) then the initialization of `c1` should generate a warning. If it doesn't then you need to enable more warnings.

Comment: I was under the impression the negative value was expressed with a single bit as an int. Oh well, I doubt I would have found out on my own. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

`char c1 = 0x86;` here `c1` by default type is `signed`

```
c1 => 1000 0110
      |
      signed bit is set(1)
```

When statement
`i1 = (unsigned int) c1;` executes sign bit of `c1` gets copied into remaining bytes of `i1` as

```
   i1 =>                         1000 0110
                                 |
                                 |<--this sign bit 
   1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1000 0110 
     f   f    f    f    f    f     8    6
```

And `i2 = (unsigned int) c2;` here `i2` and `c2` both declared as `unsigned` type so in this case `sign bit` will not be copied into remaining bytes so it prints what's the data in `1st byte` which is `0x86`